# Any way of getting current playback time for iPhone video play in pre 3.2 API?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there an API that works for pre OS 3.2 for getting the current time of a video being played back? There's this one

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

But it's 3.2 or later....

Is there any way to do this with the MPMoviePlayerController API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but no, there isn't a way to do it pre 3.2

Comment: Well, that stinks! Thanks for the answer, though.